# What is the identity of this plant with violet-colored bell-shaped flowers and red-veined lobed leaves?

Tags: identification, wildflowers

There are several of these in my yard in Augusta, GA, hardiness zone 8a. I would like to know what these are before I mow them all down.

They have violet-colored flowers growing up a central stock:

[image: Image of flowers]

The leaves are flat on the ground with red-violet-colored stems:

[image: Image of a leaf]

The roots look small and stringy:

[image: Image of the roots]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think its Salvia lyrata, a native in the USA, mostly in the Eastern parts, but technically its a woodland plant and considered a wildflower

http://www.backyardnature.net/n/h/lyresage.htm

Answer (score 6):

It looks like it is *Salvia lyrata*.

Comment: Oops, sorry, your answer wasn't there when I first started looking for a good link! Given you a vote

Comment: @bamboo but yours is a better answer than mine

Comment: Ha ha, you can't win, can you - if I hadn't spent ages looking for a really good link, my answer would have come up first - but it wouldn't have been as good. You still ID'd it correctly first anyway...

Comment: I could mark my answer, but I don't get any points for that. Even though mine was posted first, yours was better because it was more thorough.